# XCode Allocations doesnt work for C?

Tags: c, xcode

I've tried to use XCode 4.6 Allocation instrument for C programming code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){

    char c[5] = "Hello";
    unsigned char *p;
    p = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(p));
    *p = 255;

    return 0;
}
```

but it does not show any allocations:

[image: Xcode 4.6 Allocations]

Why?

Comment: Maybe it optimized it out ?

Comment: Try running your compiler without optimizations. For GCC and LLVM/clang it is compiler flag `-O0`.

Comment: cnicutar is correct. The c compiler will optomize this since there is nothing that actually needs P to be dynamically allocated.

Comment: Please don't cast the result of malloc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 2cnicutar

The problem was that Allocations instrument of XCode 4.6 was dealing with release version of the program, therefore code was optimized.

Solution is to choose "Debug" mode instead of "Release" for Profile option

[image]

Comment: that is no solution. in 99% of all cases you want to profile the release version. your sample code is just wrong